# How to split List but keep groupBy

Tags: c#, linq, split

I have a list of key/value pairs in the following form:

```
[{John:6},{Alex:100},{Peter:4},{Peter,John:5},{Alex,Kati:1}]
```

I wonder if there is a simple linq expression I can use to translate the list into

```
[{John:11},{Alex:101},{Peter:9},{Kati:1}]
```

ie split string by comma and adjust counts.

the list above is coming from following LINQ

```
var list = people.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a.Name))
.GroupBy(a => a.Name.Trim()).Select(a => new User { Name = a.Key, Items= a.Count() });
```

Comment: `John: 6` or `John:11`

Comment: Yes, John:11 fixed in the question

Comment: First list doesn't seem to be output of linq you have. Output of your linq would be enumerable list of {Name = "John", Items = 6} and so on, not {John:6}. Did you meant that you have first list in string format and you want to parse it and produce the second list as output string?

Comment: Does `Person.Name` property contain list of names or why are there commas in the key?

Comment: @ShitalShah  yes, Name/Count I tried to simplify to get to the point. To be more persise I have IEnumberable<User> there user has two fields Name and Count.

Comment: What do you mean by 'adjust counts'? Do you want to increment first occurrence of key segment, based on splitting by comma, by amount of subsequent occurrences of such key, or by values of that key?

Comment: @MikaKolari Yes, Name can be a name or comma separated list of names

Answer (score 0):

With

```
var list = new[]
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("John", 6),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Alex", 100),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Peter", 4),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Peter,John", 5),
    new KeyValuePair<string, int>("Alex,Kati", 1)
};
```

this grouping

```
var modifiedList = list.SelectMany(p => p.Key.Split(',').Select(n => new {Name = n, Number = p.Value}))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Name).Select(g => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(g.Key, g.Sum(r => r.Number)));
```

gives you the output

```
{[John, 11]}
{[Alex, 101]}
{[Peter, 9]}
{[Kati, 1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<string,int>("John", 6),
            new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Alex", 100),
            new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Peter", 4),
            new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Peter,John", 5),
            new KeyValuePair<string,int>("Alex,Kati", 1)                
        };
var result = list.SelectMany(x => x.Key.Split(','),
                                    (x, y) => new KeyValuePair<string, int>(y, x.Value))
                 .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                 .ToDictionary(key => key.Key, value => value.Sum(x => x.Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<string, int> result = keyVals
    .SelectMany(kv =>  kv.Key.Split(',').Select(name => new{ name, kv.Value }))
    .GroupBy(x => x.name)
    .ToDictionary(xg => xg.Key, xg => xg.Sum(x => x.Value));
```

Result:

```
{[John, 11]}     
{[Alex, 101]}   
{[Peter, 9]}    
{[Kati, 1]}
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/qFemyg)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

So you have classes like this

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Items { get; set; }
}
```

If I understand correctly you want to count how many times each name occurs

```
var people = new[]
{
    new Person { Name = "John" },
    new Person { Name = "John,Alex" },
    new Person { Name = "Alex" },
    new Person { Name  ="Peter,John" }
};

var list = people.SelectMany(p => p.Name.Split(','))
    .GroupBy(n => n)
    .Select(g => new User { Name = g.Key, Items = g.Count() });
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't add the numbers up the way the other solutions do. It will give John:2, Alex: 2, Peter: 1, Kati: 1.

Comment: @RobLyndon This isn't a solution how to calculate from the already calculated temp series (list). This calculates from the original source (people).

Comment: But that's not what was asked for.

Comment: @RobLyndon It's not, but from the information provided in the question that's what the user is trying to achieve. This removes the temporary list and calculates in one step instead of two.